# Pygame malfunctioning

Tags: python, pygame

This is a game for teens.

The main guy is displayed well, the time, sound and the background are showing too. 
But the bad guys and the key to press to move the bad guy are not working.

```
# 1 - Importing library
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math
import random

# 2 - Initializing the game
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
keys = {True, False, False, False}
playerpos =[100,100]
acc = [0,0]
arrows = []
badtimer = 100
badtimer1 = 0
badguys = [[300,100]]
healthvalue = 194
pygame.mixer.init()


# 3 - Loading images
player = pygame.image.load("resources/images/dude.png")
grass = pygame.image.load("resources/images/grass.png")
castle = pygame.image.load("resources/images/castle.png")
arrow = pygame.image.load("resources/images/bullet.png")
badguyimg1 = pygame.image.load("resources/images/badguy.png")
badguyimg = badguyimg1
healthbar = pygame.image.load("resources/images/healthbar.png")
health = pygame.image.load("resources/images/health.png")
gameover = pygame.image.load("resources/images/gameover.png")
youwin = pygame.image.load("resources/images/youwin.png")
# 3.1 - Load audio
hit = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/explode.wav")
enemy = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/enemy.wav")
shoot = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/shoot.wav")
hit.set_volume(0.05)
enemy.set_volume(0.05)
shoot.set_volume(0.05)
pygame.mixer.music.load('resources/audio/moonlight.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.25)


# 4 - keep looping through
# 4 - keep looping through
running = 1
exitcode = 0
# 5 - clearing the screen before drawing it again
screen.fill(0)
while running:
    badtimer -= 1
    for x in range(int(width / grass.get_width() + 1)):
        for y in range(int(height / grass.get_height() + 1)):
            screen.blit(grass, (x * 100, y * 100))
    screen.blit(castle, (0, 30))
    screen.blit(castle, (0, 135))
    screen.blit(castle, (0, 240))
    screen.blit(castle, (0, 345))

       # 6.1 - Seting player position and rotation
    position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle = math.atan2(position[1] - (playerpos[1] + 32), position[0] - (playerpos[0] + 26))
    playerrot = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 360 - angle * 57.29)
    playerpos1 = (playerpos[0] - playerrot.get_rect().width / 10, playerpos[1] - playerrot.get_rect().height / 2)
    screen.blit(playerrot, playerpos1)
    # 6.2 - Draw arrows
    for bullet in arrows:
        index = 0
        velx = math.cos(bullet[0]) * 10
        vely = math.sin(bullet[0]) * 10
        bullet[1] += velx
        bullet[2] += vely
        if bullet[1] < -64 or bullet[1] > 640 or bullet[2] < -64 or bullet[2] > 480:
            arrows.pop(index)
            # 6.3.1 - Attack castle
            for bullet in arrows:
                bullrect = pygame.Rect(arrow.get_rect())
                bullrect.left = bullet[1]
                bullrect.top = bullet[2]
                if badrect.colliderect(bullrect):
                    acc[0] += 1
                    badguys.pop(index)
                    arrows.pop(index1)
                    index1 += 1
                    badrect = pygame.Rect(badguyimg.get_rect())
                    badrect.top = badguy[1]
                    badrect.left = badguy[0]
                    if badrect.left < 64:
                        healthvalue -= random.randint(5, 20)
                        badguys.pop(index)

            # section 6.3.1 after if badrect.left<64:
            hit.play()
            # section 6.3.2 after if badrect.colliderect(bullrect):
            enemy.play()
            # 6.3.2 - Check for collisions
            index1 = 0
            # section 8, after if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            shoot.play()

            # 6.3.3 - Next bad guy

        index += 1
        for projectile in arrows:
            arrow1 = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 360 - projectile[0] * 57.29)
            screen.blit(arrow1, (projectile[1], projectile[2]))
            # 6.3 - Draw badgers
            if badtimer == 0:
                badguys.append([640, random.randint(50, 430)])
                badtimer = 100 - (badtimer1 * 2)
                if badtimer1 >= 35:
                    badtimer1 = 35
                else:
                    badtimer1 += 5
            index = 0
            for badguy in badguys:
                if badguy[0] < -64:
                    badguys.pop(index)
                badguy[0] -= 7
                index += 1
            for badguy in badguys:
                screen.blit(badguyimg, badguy)
    # 6.4 - Draw clock

    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    survivedtext = font.render(str((90000-pygame.time.get_ticks()))+":"+str((pygame.time.get_ticks())/1000%60).zfill(2), True, (0,0,0))
    textRect = survivedtext.get_rect()
    textRect.topright=[635,5]
    screen.blit(survivedtext, textRect)
    # 6.5 - Draw health bar
    screen.blit(healthbar, (5,5))
    for health1 in range(healthvalue):
        screen.blit(health, (health1+8,8))

    # 7 - updating the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # 8 - loop through the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if the event is the X button
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # if it is quit the game
            pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_w:
                    keys[0] = True
                elif event.key == K_a:
                    keys[1] = True
                elif event.key == K_s:
                    keys[2] = True
                elif event.key == K_d:
                    keys[3] = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    keys[0] = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    keys[1] = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    keys[2] = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    keys[3] = False
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                        acc[1] += 1
                        arrows.append(
                            [math.atan2(position[1] - (playerpos1[1] + 32), position[0] - (playerpos1[0] + 26)),
                             playerpos1[0] + 32, playerpos1[1] + 32])

                    # 9 - Move player
                    if keys[0]:
                        playerpos[1] -= 5
                    elif keys[2]:
                        playerpos[1] += 5
                    if keys[1]:
                        playerpos[0] -= 5
                    elif keys[3]:
                        playerpos[0] += 5
            exit(0)
    #10 - Win/Lose check
    if pygame.time.get_ticks()>=90000:
        running=0
        exitcode=1
    if healthvalue<=0:
        running=0
        exitcode=0
    if acc[1]!=0:
        accuracy=acc[0]*1.0/acc[1]*100
    else:
        accuracy=0
# 11 - Win/lose display
if exitcode==0:
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    text = font.render("Accuracy: "+str(accuracy)+"%", True, (255,0,0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery+24
    screen.blit(gameover, (0,0))
    screen.blit(text, textRect)
else:
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
    text = font.render("Accuracy: "+str(accuracy)+"%", True, (0,255,0))
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
    textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery+24
    screen.blit(youwin, (0,0))
    screen.blit(text, textRect)
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Hello.. could you also be specific explaining the exact functionalities that do not work.

Comment: I think you have wrong indetations and you draw badguy inside loop `for bullet in arrows:` so it may never show up. You can put `print()` in different places with different messages to see which part of code is executed - it can help to find problem.

Comment: the same problem is with keys. You have wrong indentations so you check keys inside `if event.type == pygame.QUIT` so it will be checked only when you close window.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong indentations.

You check keys inside `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:` so they are checked only when you close window.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # check if the event is the X button
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        # if it is quit the game
        pygame.quit()

    # the same indentation like for other event.type
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_w:
            keys[0] = True
        elif event.key == K_a:
            keys[1] = True
        elif event.key == K_s:
            keys[2] = True
        elif event.key == K_d:
            keys[3] = True

    # the same indentation like for other event.type
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            keys[0] = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            keys[1] = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            keys[2] = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            keys[3] = False

    # the same indentation like for other event.type
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        acc[1] += 1
        arrows.append(
           [math.atan2(position[1] - (playerpos1[1] + 32), position[0] - (playerpos1[0] + 26)),
           playerpos1[0] + 32, playerpos1[1] + 32])

# it should be outside `for event` loop
# 9 - Move player
if keys[0]:
    playerpos[1] -= 5
elif keys[2]:
    playerpos[1] += 5
if keys[1]:
    playerpos[0] -= 5
elif keys[3]:
    playerpos[0] += 5
```

---

Similar problem is with drawing badguy.

---

**BTW:** instead of all thess settings and checkings of keys you could use   [pygame.key.get_pressed](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed)

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_w]:
    playerpos[1] -= 5
elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
    playerpos[1] += 5
if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    playerpos[0] -= 5
elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
    playerpos[0] += 5
```